# custom UITableViewCell to create a Grid layout

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, grid-layout

I'm trying to create a UITableView where each UITableViewCell has three UIButton objects side by side, all clickable.

I want to hide the outline of the tableViewCell and make it unclickable (only allow for the user to click on the UIView objects on top of the cell).

I'm trying to create a grid layout -- I know about GMGridView and other grid layouts, but I don't want to add more dependencies in my project.

How do you create this custom grid layout using UITableView? Specifically, how do you
1) hide the tableViewCell outline
2) make the cell unclickable, but the subview objects on top clickable.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about in a standard table view style, or grouped style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a partial answer, you can make all of your cells unselectable by implementing this function in your tableviewcontroller/tableviewdelegate

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return nil;
}
```

And also set your cells' selection style to none

**EDIT**

As for hiding the "outline" you just need to set your table view's separator style to "none" as well.

And lastly, the hard part: making it a grid layout.  I've had my own attempts at achieving this in previous projects.  What I ended up doing was simply having a custom `UITableViewCell` that has evenly spaced labels, and set their display accordingly.  Getting it to scroll horizontally though, that I never mastered.

Comment: Thanks! If I set the cells' selection style to none, will the subviews on the cell still be selectable?

Comment: Yes, it only changes the selection *style* so when you click on it, it doesn't change the background color or anything

Comment: @user1467188 I wouldn't be surprised if Apple released an API to achieve some kind of grid layout in the near future.  I believe it is already possible in the Android SDK, and a lot of people want this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to do this in UITableView. I know people who've done this but it took them a very long time to get it working properly. I would highly suggest using a library. Otherwise, wait for the next iOS release.